# substituting previous row in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to tag a cell in a row which has a flagged value just after it.

```
ROWNO   f1  f2
1       0   0
2       0   1
3       1   0
4       0   0
5       0   1
6       1   0
7       0   0
8       0   0
9       0   1
10      1   0
```

In the above data I have variable "f1" i want to create "f2" from or using "f1".
Say in row 6 I have "f1" as 1 so for "f2" I need to have the value 1 in row 5.
How would I do it in SAS?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963658/calculating-moving-average-using-do-loop-in-sas/18964513#18964513) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833155/script-the-next-row-data-for-current/31838586#31838586) for other similar treatments.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Cleb....by actual need is to script a row above the row which has a 1 . I tried it using lag any trying to create single dimensional array, none of the procedures worked out...only I was able to script the row after the value 1.